# How to eliminate /usr/local from pre compiler and linker paths?

Tags: gcc, linker

I am trying to build an open source package and running into trouble involving a conflict with a prototype library I have installed in `/usr/local`, where the "right" version resides in `/usr`.

```
% (make distclean>/dev/null; ./configure > no_env_conf.log 2>& 1; make > no_env_make.log 2>&1 && echo Success || echo 'Build Error')
Build Error
```

I want to configure and compile without `/usr/local` in the precompile or linker paths. I thought I could do that by specifying the appropriate environment variables, but that does not quite work:

```
% (make distclean>/dev/null; CFLAGS=-I/usr/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib ./configure > no_env_conf.log 2>& 1; make > no_env_make.log 2>&1 && echo Success || echo 'Build Error')
Build Error
```

But if I simply remove `/usr/local` from the filesystem then everything works:

```
% (sudo mv /usr/local /usr/local_off; make distclean>/dev/null; ./configure > no_env_conf.log 2>& 1; make > no_env_make.log 2>&1 && echo Success || echo 'Compile Error'; sudo mv /usr/local_off /usr/local )
Success
```

Is there a way to eliminate `/usr/local` from the paths used by the pre compiler and linker?  I would especially like something that could be handled by `configure` options or environment variables.

*Specific context: I am building `ccache` on OSX Lion where I have installed v1.2.6 of `zlib` in `/usr/local`, while the required one in `/usr` happens to be 1.2.5.  This build actually happens as part of a wider script-controlled build of MythTV and all its dependencies including `ccache`.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From "man gcc":

```
-nostdinc
   Do not search the standard system directories for header files.
   Only the directories you have specified with -I options (and the
   directory of the current file, if appropriate) are searched.
```

Also note that while pre-compilers [do exist](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/basics/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.zappldev/zappldev_111.htm), you are not using one -- you are using a regular compiler, so you should stop calling it "pre compiler".

Comment: If one is going to use --nostdinc, then one has to restore the remainder of the standard directories.  How exactly does one get a listing of those?

Comment: @BrianB Try `gcc -v -xc /dev/null`